# Equatable == function implemented but still crashes

Tags: ios, swift, equatable

In my app, I have a class `Video` which implements the `Equatable` protocol because I need to use the `==(lhs:,rhs:) -> Bool` function. My class was as this :

```
class Video: Equatable {
    var url: URL!
    // Some other vars
}

func ==(lhs: Video, rhs: Video) -> Bool {
    return lhs.url == rhs.url
}
```

It always worked for me but some users had crashes with the reason `protocol witness for static Equatable.== infix(A, A) -> Bool in conformance Video`.

So I tried another way to implement this function which is

```
class Video {
    var url: URL!
    // Some other vars
}

extension Video: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Video, rhs: Video) -> Bool {
        return lhs.url == rhs.url
    }
}
```

But the crashes still occur for some users and I don't understand why... Does someone already had this issue or know how to solve it?

Comment: `!` is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `url` can be `nil` you have to consider this case in the implementation of `==`

```
func ==(lhs: Video, rhs: Video) -> Bool {
    guard let lURL = lhs.url, let rURL = rhs.url else { return false }
    return lURL == rURL
}
```

If your design treats two objects with both `nil` urls as equal you have to add this case, too.

Comment: If both URLs are `nil`, you should probably return `true`.

Comment: @ganzogo It depends on the needs, maybe `nil` values are irrelevant. Anyway the code avoids the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I didn't think about the case the url is nil... My Video class also has an asset so if the url is nil, I return the comparison between the two assets.
Thanks